# Why are different browsers generating different strings?

Tags: javascript, string

I am constructing a string by concatenating the first 100 unicode characters, like this

```
var str = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(i);
}
```

In Firefox and Chrome, `str` has the value I expected, i.e.

`` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abc ``

Internet Explorer and Opera, on the other hand, return the empty string.

[You can test it out in your browser on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xLX4K/)

What is causing this discrepancy in behavior?

Comment: If you use alert you can clearly see some character display as the block, simply because there is nothing to print and I suspect both IE and Opera handle badly the fact that your request a character that doesn't exists for a given code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first Unicode codepoint represents the NUL character, which probably makes some browsers think they reached end of string (following the C convention).